Scoped E2e testing on a microservice
As many, we use microservices in my company and there's some debate in my group whether a microservice has e2e tests on it's own.
I know e2e tests by definition are user flow tests.
Lets take for example an auditing microservice, here we defined to 2 seperate  repos/pipelines, audit-backend/audit-ui.
Lets say for the audit-backend for example:
The service receives audits in some https api call, does some processing on it and serves the data on some other apis, lets say we have the following apis: /api/audits (POST/GET).
Can you write e2e tests as part of the audit-backend pipeline(independant deployment process), or only integration tests?
(Some devs here claim that you can write an 'e2e' tests here by mocking the client), Whats your opinions, does it count as e2e test or is it just an integration test?

Does it make a difference for the quality of the test how you call it?

@DocBrown, while I see your point, the names we give certain kinds of tests allow developers to have conversations where we make assumptions in lieu of a more detailed discussion. This becomes an issue of communication. I say "end-to-end test" thinking we are making API calls to a microservice, but you think "open a web browser and navigate the user interface." Those tests verify the application at very different levels of abstraction, and have very different execution environments with a very different number of failure scenarios.

I would first start by researching what other people define as an end-to-end test: https://www.google.com/search?q=end+to+end+test+definition - this can help prime a conversation with your team.

End to End tests are perhaps the best defined tests.
Is your test of the microservice part of a larger flow END to END? obviously not, because one of those ends is the UI, and it's not in the test.
Is a UI test with a mock api client END to END? obviously not, because one of those ends is the database.
When someone asks, "do we have end to end tests" they mean is the system tested with all the bits put together. Not "are all of the individual parts of the system tested in isolation?".
